# Completing uWSGI/Nginx setup for Django site

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

So a few months ago I setup a django blog on an Ubuntu server with Digital Ocean using this tutorial

Note: please excuse my links below but SO will not let me post more than 2 links due to my account's lack of points.

digitalocean[ dot] com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

the only problem was this was done as a brand new blog and I wanted to put my own one that was on my local computer there but I tried to do this by just uploading files via ssh to copy over the old ones and ended up making a mess and had to scrap it.

I just started again on a new server and have done the basic setup along with cloning my own django blog onto the server from Github as well as installing postgresql and now Im following this:

uwsgi-docs.readthedocs[ dot ]io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

So far I have completed the following successfully:

installed uwsgi

run the test.py 'hello world' file successfully with:

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file test.py
```

test run the django site on the sever with:

```
python manage.py runserver my_ip_here:8000
```

the above appears to be working as I can see the bare basics of my site but not css etc)

done a test run of the site with:

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi
```

run collect static which seems to have been successful
installed nginx and I can see the 'Welcome to nginx!' when visiting the ip
created the mysite_nginx.conf file in my main directory

**What Im having problems with**

this part from the readthedocs tutorial doesn't work for me, when I visit the paths of any of my images:

*To check that media files are being served correctly, add an image called media.png to the    /path/to/your/project/project/media directory, then visit example.com:8000/media/media.png - if this works, you’ll know at least that nginx is serving files correctly.*

running this does NOT return the 'hello world' test that I should see

```
uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py
```

after making the appropriate changes in mysite_nginx.conf this doesn't return anything at :8000 either (my sock file is present though)

```
uwsgi --socket mysite.sock --wsgi-file test.py
```

**Some other things to add:**

my error.log at /var/log/nginx/error.log is empty with no messages in, not sure if this is normal

this is my mysite_nginx.conf file - http://pastebin[ dot ]com/CGcc8unv

when I run this command as specified by the readthedocs tutorial

```
uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py
```

and then go to mysite:8001 I get these errors in the shell

```
invalid request block size: 21573 (max 4096)...skip
invalid request block size: 21573 (max 4096)...skip
```

I setup the symlink as the readthedocs tutorial specified and have double checked that.

I do not have an nginx .ini file yet as where Im at in the readthedocs tutorial it hasn't specified to creat that yet.

as I said earlier I can still return my site running some uwsgi commands and I can see the 'welcome to nginx' message at my site/ip.

Comment: Post your nginx configuration.

Comment: I haven't created one yet as Im up to 'nginx and uWSGI and test.py' in the readthedocs tutorial where it hasn't specified to make it yet and it says at this point I should be able to see my media files at example.com:8000/media/media.jpg which I can't and also that I should be able to do a  test run of the site with 'uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py' which I also cannot do...

Comment: also where should I create the nginx ini file? The Digital Ocean tutorial says to put it here /etc/uwsgi/sites but readthedocs doesn't specify any specific location...

Comment: Normally uwsgi doesn't serve static files, nginx does, which is probably the reason why your site doesn't work normally. The graphic at http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/21/how-django-static-files-work-in-production/ might help.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides ok thanks will check that out and maybe start again with this tutorial